# What is the volume of menstrual flow in non human hominidae?

Tags: menstrual-cycle

I'm looking for reliable data related to menstruation in animals, with especial focus on apes. I have found that some articles and cientific studies point that only chimpanzees have copious menstruations, but there is not refrence to the volume of menstrual flow at all, and what is more intriguing this alleged copious menses are not consistent with two important observations, first that in a studied carried on some captive female chimpanzees only a keeper reported an observation of menstrual flow in a female on one single day (and the researchers didn't agree it was actual menstruation), and the second one that field researchers reported of a period of adolescent infertility in young female chimpanzees, about two years in which they have intercourses but not pregnancies, and yet they didn't notice a sign of menstruation.

Comment: I'm trying to get to a more deep understanding of the evolutive process of menstruation. I'm familiar with the study of Emera and Romero about the evolution of menstruation and think it has left this important matter outside the box. Also I want that the wikipedia article about menstruation in mammals, which is rather ambigous, get to this point in a clear manner.